# Trouble understanding list and data frame interactions

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames and could use help understanding the conventions for calling some of the data because I am getting my wires crossed.
I am trying to combine multiple columns from MANY data frames into one data frame, and ultimately I will illustrate trends over time using line charts, primarily. However, I'm stuck on trying to make the one data frame.

Here is some sample data that will create two data frames in a list which is representative of my data structure:

```
ValueID <- c(1610, 1638, 1651, 1652, 1741, 1748, 1759, 1761, 1766)
Area <- c(136300, 73900, 230000, 178700, 54700, 4500, 120000, 3400, 45000)
Dep2001 <- c(6.14, 5.02, 5.84, 5.84, 4.69, 6.84, 5.09, 5.34, 7.84)
Dep2002 <- c(8.23, 7.11, 7.93, 7.93, 6.78, 8.93, 7.18, 7.43, 9.93)
a <- data.frame(ValueID, Area, Dep2001)
b <- data.frame(ValueID, Area, Dep2002)
aa <- list(a, b)
names(aa) <- c("a", "b")
```

I'm trying to create the one data frame with ValueID, Area, Dep2001, Dep2002, Dep2003, etc. (as you can see, each data frame has a common ID field in `ValueID` ) using an `apply` function or `for` loop to add columns Dep2001, Dep2002, etc. from a list of hundreds of data frames.

I started like this:

```
q <- names(aa)
bb <- as.data.frame(aa[[1]][c(1:2)])
apply(bb, q, cbind, aa)
```

...but I don't think I'm on the right track here.

So, I was trying to figure out how to call a list of all the "Dep" columns (which are also always the third column). But, while `aa[[1]][3]` calls the third column of the first data frame and `aa[c(1:2)]` calls the first two data frames, I can't get a combination of some sort to work that calls a list of each of the third/Dep columns in each data frame; here's an example I've tried that doesn't work:

```
aa[[c(1:2)][3]
```

I'm fairly new to R, and pretty new to programming at all, so there is probably a pretty basic solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), aa)`?

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus, this is what I was looking for.  I don't think I would have figured it out though without the help below from LegalizeIt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Area` and `ValueID` are always ordered the same in all the `data.frame`s

```
res <- data.frame(ValueID, Area, as.data.frame(lapply(aa, `[`, 3)))
```

`apply` functions take arguments as a list, so you often don't need to create an anonymous function.  In this case the function is `[`, one of the subsetting functions, and you pass it the argument "3", telling it to take the third column.  If `Area` and `ValueID` are not sorted, you could use `Reduce` and `merge` as suggested.

edit: since your `data.frames` have different rows

```
Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by=c("ValueID", "Area"), all=T), aa)
```

Comment: This is good--it added the other column the way I was looking for it to, and I was not aware of the '[' subsetting function before.  However, when I try it on my actual data, I receive `Error in data.frame(` ...  `arguments imply differing number of rows:` ....

Comment: `[` is the function you use when you write something like `a[,3]`.  The error is because your `data.frames` must have different numbers of rows.  In that case, the `Area` and `ValueID` columns will be different, so you need to use another method - see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the additional edit @LegalizeIt; this is the solution I was looking for.  There's definitely some syntax and functions here that I wasn't familiar with, so I'll be studying those to figure out why they worked the way they did so I can use them in the future!

Answer (score 0):

This returns the a list of the values of the third column of your list of dfs:

```
bb = lapply(aa, function(x) x[,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data frame, maybe you could try rbindlist to convert to one data set, then dcast.data.table to convert it in a row format.

something like that:

```
data <- rbindlist(aa)
data[, type := paste0("Dep", floor(seq(from = 2001, to = 2003-0.001, by = 1/9)))]

dcast.data.table(data, ValueID + Area  ~ type, value.var = "Dep2001", fun = mean)
```

Comment: What is "rbindlist()"?  I don't see any documentation for this function in any packages or libraries?  Please let me know so I can try downloading the package with that function and try your solution.  Also, what is ":=" in the second line? R thinks it is a function.

Comment: package data.table.

It should be one of the fastest package for data management. It worth to learn about.